# Get file content from shared document in Sharepoint 2013 using JSOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-jsom

I have excel file in shared document in sharepoint 2013. I want to store the content of that file in array variable and send it to server side for processing.

I am getting the client context loaded,but i want to get the records present inside in the file. I have excel file present inside SharedDocument/test folder

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(viewfiles, "sp.js");
function viewfiles(){ 
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('Documents');
var query = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();
query.set_folderServerRelativeUrl('http://win-mjphj36pn7d:55555/sites/Demo/Shared%20Documents/test');
allItems = list.getItems(query);
context.load(allItems, 'Include(Title, ContentType, File)');
context.executeQueryAsync(
Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {
                     var fileUrls = ""; var fileUrls = "";
                      var ListEnumerator = this.allItems.getEnumerator();
                       while(ListEnumerator.moveNext())
                       {
                        var currentItem = ListEnumerator.get_current();
                        var _contentType = currentItem.get_contentType();
                         if(_contentType.get_name() != "Folder")
                           {
                            var File = currentItem.get_file();
                            if(File != null)
                              {
                               fileUrls += File.get_serverRelativeUrl() + '\n';
                              }
                           }
                       }
                      alert(fileUrls);
                }),

Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {
          alert("failed. Message:" + args.get_message());                    
             })
            );
```

Please suggest how i get all data in the file in a array var or string

Comment: By all data you mean the metadata (columns and so) stored in sharepoint or the actual binary content of the document?

Comment: @baywet I needed actual binary content

Answer (score 0):

Apparently for some reason the openbinary method from  CSOM is not available in JSOM (or a least not documented).
So I'd suggest that you first try within the console in the browser's context to see if it's here. Otherwrise see the [REST API documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292553.aspx#Anchor_1) (second example) to retrieve the binary value.
Here is the [jsom documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246089.aspx) and the [CSOM documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile_methods.aspx) of this same aspect.